# How to use the latitude/longitude of points when using scikit-learn's Gaussian Process Regression？

Tags: python, scikit-learn, geolocation, interpolation

I'm trying to **interpolate** some data from air monitoring stations.

Almost each record have an air quality value and their latitude, longitude. But there are some records lacking values.
*For example*, the data just like this:

```
116° 42° 10
117° 43° missing
120° 20° 1000
```

I want to use the **scikit-learn's GPR** (GaussianProcessRegressor) to interpolate the missing values.

I know that the 2-D data can be processed like the last answer in this problem
 [Python - Kriging (Gaussian Process) in scikit_learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489610/python-kriging-gaussian-process-in-scikit-learn)

**My problem is that:** I shouldn't use the latitude and longitude to do this task directly, beacause the earth is a sphere so the latitude/longitude is not an **usual** flat 2-D grid.

I want to ask how to define the distance function between points when using the scikit-learn's GPR, or should I just project these lat/lon points to flat and use them? I hadn't try this because the precesion loss during projection made me sad :(

Thx for any suggestion :)

ps. The distance between two lat/lon points can be calculate by Haversine formula like [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Comment: Using this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240915/interpolation-of-geodata-on-surface-of-a-sphere) post as a guide, I'd suggest that you use a geodesy package (e.g. geographiclib) to generate geodesics to measure the distance between your "unknown" point and some nearby known points.  Then use inverse distance interpolation to predict a value for your unknown quantity.

Comment: Thx for your method but I'm sry :( to say that I must use the GPR or kriging method beacause it's required. This method is just ok for simple situation.

Answer (score 0):

The Variogram()  constructor has a parameter dist_func='euclidean'. You could try replacing euclidean with a custom haversine function.

See scipy.spatial.distance.pdist

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

dm = pdist(X, lambda u, v: np.sqrt(((u-v)**2).sum()))

I haven't tried it.